# Change image of accessory view of a table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessoryview

I wish to replace the icon of UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton with a custom icon. I have tried to replace the accessoryView with a UIButton which contains the custom image, but the button is showing like 20 pixels from the right edge of the cell.

Is there a better way to replace the icon, or to move the accessoryview all the way to the right?

Comment: If your using a custom UITableView cell, an alternative would be to just create the button in the custom cell's XIB and not use the accessory view at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom cell and create UIButton in the custom cell's and give the UIButton background image like "DetailButton"
May this help you.

Answer (score 4):

```
#pragma mark Tableview Datasource and Delegate Method

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   UICollectionViewCell *Cell =(UICollectionViewCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

 Cell.accessoryView = [[ UIImageView alloc ] 
                       initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Something" ]];
return cell;
}
```